# Folder Access Restrictions Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess

I have the following directory structure on my Apache web root.

I would like to restrict the "source" folder to the outside world. Currently it can be accessed via its url.

How can this be done?

[image: index page]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a .htaccess file inside the source folder:

```
order allow deny
deny from all
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment i added .htaccess file but no luck still i can access the source folder and content via url

Comment: @Roshan Then it looks like your .htaccess file is being ignored. Check your site configuration in Apache that it allows .htaccess override files.

Comment: @Roshan The site will be defined somewhere - either inside the `httpd.conf` file, or inside a `sites-available` file. There will be a `<Directory>` section - you need to add `AllowOverride All` inside that section. Also, check that `AccessFileName` is set to `.htaccess` and not anything else. Then restart Apache with `apache2ctl restart`.

Answer (score 1):

```
chmod -R o-rwx source
```

this will remove permissions for the outside world to the directory source and all of its content

Comment: -1 Assuming Apache is the server, it needs to have access to the files, but Apache is the same user that will attempt to access the files if a naughty person goes via the browser. i.e. somebody can still execute `source/notpublic.php?action=dosomethingnaughty`.

Comment: this will hide but then my client/server php files can not access the source folder then it giving server error thanks for answer

Comment: well, you didn't specify that in the question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also put an index.html file in each directory with a forbidden access notice as index.html is the default default file to be viewed when opening a directory.

Comment: This prevents browsing of the directory, but it doesn't prevent someone executing a script. For example, somebody could run `source/notpublic.php?action=dosomethingnasty`.

Answer (score -1):

You could make it seem like the directory doesn't exist by inserting index.php and writing

```
<?php
  header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
?>
```